# how can get id from set of elements and save in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to save ids from set of element in an array but only saved the id of last element.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prince666i/uNEcX/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="div" id="d1">DIV-1</div>
<div class="div" id="d2">DIV-2</div>
<div class="div" id="d3">DIV-3</div>
<div class="div" id="d4">DIV-4</div>
<div class="div" id="d5">DIV-5</div>

<hr>

<div id="test" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.div').each(function(n){
    var test = new Array();
    test = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#test').html(test); 
});
```

Comment: I fixed your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uNEcX/3/)

Comment: @Pinal the shortest answer ever seen :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `map()`:

```
var ids = $('.div').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
$('#test').text(ids.join(','));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FEv39/)

[API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/map)

Comment: What does `get()` do?

Comment: `map` returns an array wrapped in a jQuery object. `get` returns the array itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `.map()`:

```
$('#test').html($('.div').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).get().join());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uNEcX/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
   var test = new Array();
    $('.div').each(function(n){
        test.push($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#test').html(test); 
    });
```

This will get all of them, you were re-initializing your array on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Collect your id's in an array and then write result to a div :

```
var ids = [];

$('.div').each(function(n){
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('#test').html(ids.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with your own code to help you understand what's happening:

```
// create the array outside of the loop - don't recreate it on each iteration of the loop.
var test = new Array();

// loop over the divs and push each ID into the array
$('.div').each(function(n){
    test.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

// display the IDs
$('#test').html(test.join(', '));
```

Example using your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNEcX/5/